# Cannot draw italic text in Firefox canvas

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, italic

When drawing italicized text in canvas, Firefox would render them as normal for fonts like `Impact`.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "italic 40px Impact";
ctx.fillText("Impact", 0, 40);
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TYKq/)

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Impact doesn't come with an italic version. You can see this when you view it in a font viewer (like Mac Font Book). Browsers fake the italics on fonts that don't have it, but Firefox is not yet faking it in the canvas. If you try a font that has italics, like Arial, it works in the canvas.

There's some discussion about this here: [Italic doesn't work on all fonts in Firefox](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/fabricjs/eqGPHYBb7tQ/RAMN0R3sxFcJ)

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

```js
ctx.font = "italic 40px Arial";
```

[image: with arial]

Comment: I know it is font-specific and I have read that discussion as well. I was thinking if there are any workarounds for it.

Comment: The only workaround I know of is to skew text manually by skewing canvas context before rendering the text.